# Are there questions that could use the tag "vocabulary" without referring to taxonomy terms?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have both [vocabulary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) and [taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy).
Are there cases where [vocabulary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is not referring to the "container" of taxonomy terms, for which [taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy) could be used?

Comment: if nobody can come up with a valid reason to *keep* two similar tags, I support merging them by default

Comment: I wait another day, or two, and then I will proceed with merging the tags.

Comment: I believe that these two tags should be merged as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal *vocabulary* and *taxonomy term* are related terms; a vocabulary is a container of taxonomy terms, and *vocabulary* is not used with another meaning.

I merged the tags, and made [vocabulary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) a synonym of [taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy).